# Random generated vector in C++ is not changing values

Tags: c++, random, stdvector

My class contains some vector matrix of type:

```
typedef std::vector<double> MyArray;
typedef std::vector<MyArray> MyMatrix;
```

Class has an `update()` method, and on each call it should generate a new random matrix, and old place in `std::map<double, MyMatrix, std::greater<double>> rankedMyMatrix_;`.

Update method looks approximately like this:

```
void MyClass::update(...){
     ...
     this->generateMyMatrix();  // Generates new random currentMyMatrix_
     ...
     rankedMyMatrix_.insert({matrixRank_, currentMyMatrix_});
     ...
}
```

Method `generateMyMatrix()` looks like this:

```
void MyClass::generateMyMatrix(){
     std::random_device rd;
     std::mt19937 mt(rd());
     std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-1, 1);
     for (int i = 0; i < noMotors_; i++) {
         MyArray array(MaxArraySamples, 0);
         for (int j = 0; j < MaxArraySamples; j = j + steps) {
             array[j] = dist(mt);
         }
     currentMyMatrix_.push_back(array);
     }
}
```

Trouble is that on each push to `rankedMyMatrix_` map, on new `update()` it generates same matrix. Or it does not write to it? Probably I am missing something here, so any help would be appreciated.

## UPDATE

Here is code that can be compiled and tested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    MyClass* c;
    c = new MyClass();

    int x = 0;

    while (x<3){
        c->update();
        x++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef PROBA_MYCLASS_H
#define PROBA_MYCLASS_H

#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<double> MyArray;
typedef std::vector <MyArray> MyMatrix;

const int NoMotors = 4;
const int MaxArraySamples = 10;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();

    ~MyClass();

    void update();

private:
    std::map<double, MyMatrix, std::greater<double>> rankedMyMatrix_;

    MyMatrix currentMyMatrix_;
    int matrixRank_;

    void generateMyMatrix();

    void writeCurrent();

};

#endif //PROBA_MYCLASS_H
```

Class file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

MyClass::MyClass() {
    currentMyMatrix_.reserve(NoMotors);
    matrixRank_ = 0;
}

MyClass::~MyClass() { }

void MyClass::update() {

    this->generateMyMatrix();  // Generates new random currentMyMatrix_

    rankedMyMatrix_.insert({matrixRank_, currentMyMatrix_});
    matrixRank_++;

    this->writeCurrent();
}

void MyClass::generateMyMatrix() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-1, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < NoMotors; i++) {
        MyArray array(MaxArraySamples, 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < MaxArraySamples; j = j + 3) {
            array[j] = dist(mt);
        }
        currentMyMatrix_.push_back(array);
    }
}

void MyClass::writeCurrent() {
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    std::string uri = "/tmp/output/test";
    outputFile.open(uri + std::to_string(matrixRank_) + ".txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxArraySamples; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NoMotors; j++) {
            outputFile << currentMyMatrix_[j][i] << " ";
        }
        outputFile << std::endl;
    }
    outputFile.close();
}
```

And CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(proba)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp MyClass.h MyClass.cpp)
add_executable(proba ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Still it gives a same output. I'm clueless.

Comment: Before I Mjölnir this, just to be sure: Are you indeed using MinGW?

Comment: @baum-mit-augen No, Mac

Comment: Then please tell us which version of what compiler and standard library you are using. But if it's gcc/libstdc++, it's probably the same issue as in the MinGW case.

Comment: Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Standard library is C++11

Comment: Hm, unless Apple broke something in the normal clang code (which is possible), this should work fine. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @baum-mit-augen I added example program. It behaves a same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finaly solved problem. Error was with using

```
currentMyMatrix_.push_back(array);
```

It always push new values at end, so code would see only first `noMotors_` arrays.This is a solution:

```
currentMyMatrix_.at(i) = array;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are likely generating the same random sequence time and time again because you're resetting your generator.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device

> std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. In this case each std::random_device object may generate the same number sequence.